# SQL Server Query Trace

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to capture the SQL query code generated by a packaged application used in our company.  I need to develop custom SQL reports against the SQL Server back-end, since the app (actually, a PowerBuilder app) is weak on reporting.  Unfortunately, the software vendor does not provide any information to map the application forms to the underlying tables.  So I'd like to be able to open the app in a test environment and capture the SQL sent to the server as I open various forms.

I understand that SQL Profiler is what I should use, but if it's not available, do I have any other options?  As far as SQL Profiler is concerned, I understand that I could purchase a Developer version of SQL Server so long as I'm not running it against Production.

Thanks.

Wayne

Answer (score 0):

you could try running a query along these lines and then try to pick out the SQL that you are interested in:

```
SELECT deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], dest.TEXT AS [Query]
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

(run the query whilst your reports are running)