# what sql statement sent to server from ado.net application (MS SQL provider)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net, data-access-layer

I want to know what sql statement sent to the server from my ado.net based application for loging exceptions and debugging.
I  use generic DAL that handle MS SQL connection provider.

I found this query while searching SO:

```
SELECT deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], dest.TEXT AS [Query]
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

reference: [SQL Server Query Trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561837/sql-server-query-trace)

and many others in SO

This sql code  can catch queries if they are executed from within SSMS (SQL server Management Studio)

but  CANNOT  catch queries if they are sent from my Ado.net application connected with MS sql database server.

My question:

Why I can't catch queries if they are sent from Ado.net based application using this code?

Is there other way (sql code/ c# code) to catch the real sql statements sent from my application (like what i get in sql profiller)

Comment: The query will find a query that is cached regardless of how executed.  So perhaps the query isn't being cached or was evicted before the DMV query was run.  Rather than use DMVs for this purpose, consider a trace using Extended Events or SQL Trace (Profiler).

Comment: SQL profiler need online interaction , i need some code for  logging

Comment: You can script the trace from the Profiler for unattended server-side tracing from the Profiler File-->Export-->Script Trace Definition menu.  Modify the script to specify the desired file name pattern, file size, rollover, etc.

Comment: Extended events or SQL Trace (Profiler) is on the level of server which collect many information. I know that i can filter data, but i prefer to start from the scope of application connection/commands/.

Comment: A trace that includes login/logout, batch completed, and rpc completed events will capture use of connection and commands.  To make the filter easy, specfy `Application Name` in the connection string and filter on that.

Comment: I try trace events and struggle to resolve a problem : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Instapi, Version=13.0.0.0 with sql 2012

Comment: Is the error returned by SSMS?  Try the latest version (SQL Server 2016 July Update).  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx

Comment: The error raises  from my c# test application. have a look  for the source code  and error message in the url : http://pasted.co/8989597c

Answer (score 1):

If your DAL is using the abstract IDbConnection and IDbCommand interfaces, and you have a common factory for instantiating your IDbConnection, you could create your own implementation of IDbConnection that overrides CreateCommand to return your own implementation of IDbCommand which logs ExecuteReader, ExecuteNonQuery, and ExecuteScalar before calling the real underlying objects:

```
    public class MyDbConnection : IDbConnection {
        private IDbConnection src;
        public MyDbConnection(IDbConnection src) {
            this.src = src;
        }
        public IDbCommand CreateCommand() {
            return new MyDbCommand(src.CreateCommand());
        }
        //TODO create pass-through implementations of the rest of IDbConnection methods...
    }

    public class MyDbCommand : IDbCommand {
        private IDbCommand src;
        public MyDbCommand(IDbCommand src) {
            this.src = src;
        }

        public int ExecuteNonQuery() {
            log.Info(src.CommandText);
            return src.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        public IDataReader ExecuteReader() {
            log.Info(src.CommandText);
            return src.ExecuteReader();
        }

        public IDataReader ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) {
            log.Info(src.CommandText);
            return src.ExecuteReader(behavior);
        }

        public object ExecuteScalar() {
            log.Info(src.CommandText);
            return src.ExecuteScalar();
        }

        //TODO create pass-through implementations of the rest of IDbCommand methods and properties...
    }
```

Now, wherever you were creating your IDbConnection, return new MyDbConnection(theRealDbConnection) instead...

Comment: src.CommandText isn't the complete sql sent to the server when there are parameters. MyDbCommand will send sql as {sp_executesql statement, Parameter_types, Parameter_values } and log only logs third of information  without parameters. I want to catch the complete  sp_executesql. I can compose it and logging in my current DAL,but I want to know the actual sql query sent by ado.net which as captured by sql profiler tool. This implementation will not produce the complete SQl query sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, sorry, I misunderstood the question.  My previous answer showed how to capture what your app was sending to the sql client, not what the sql client was sending to the server.

In order to capture SQL statements that are sent by the SQL client to the server, you will need to use sp_trace_create and related trace functions to configure sql server to send trace information back to your application.

This technet article may be helpful to you: [SQL Trace](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191006(v=sql.105).aspx)